# Fitting one data pattern to another in Python

Tags: python, data-analysis, curve-fitting

Let there be an pattern that is known at certain points, but has an unknown functional form. Let there also be a data set. Both, as far as the computer can be concerned, are just a set of (x,y) values.

However, I still want to fit my pattern to the data with a simple relation, `a*P+b`, and I want to find the best values for the parameters `a,b` with an actual fitting routine. How can I do this with something akin to `optimize.curve_fit()`, or do I have to invent my own method?

Comment: Use optimize.curve_fit. There are plenty of examples. Also see https://realpython.com/linear-regression-in-python/

Comment: as far as I can tell from the documentation, optimize,curve_fit() requires a model function to be passed, and I don't have that.

Comment: @BrandonMyers if i understand well, you have data points and you want to fit a curve in them and get its parameters?

Comment: No, I have basically 2 sets of data points. One is a known pattern (a K7 stellar spectrum, to be specific), and then data (spectrum of another system we want to type). 

The pattern has no functional form, there is no `y=mx+b` type thing for this pattern, it is just a bunch of exact (x,y) data points. I want to know what the best parameters are to scale these points to match the data. 

In other words, Given a data set of the form {(Dx, Dy)} and a pattern set of the form {(Px,Py)}, is there a function that gives a,b such that Dy-aPy+b is minimized.

Comment: @BrandonMyers Your model function is f(x) = ax + b.

Comment: I assure you, it isn't. I want to scale a pattern I know at certain points (it is a stellar spectrum, a K7 star) to match another spectrum as best as possible by scaling it, and maybe applying a bias.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve has a name. It is a regression problem. You want to find a relation between data points and how they are linked.

Having said that, you can look into `LinearRegression()` from sci-kit learn. It would be useful for your case.

Note: It might be possible that maybe linear regression can't capture whatever relation your data holds then try other models like `SVM` with a non linear kernel or maybe NN. (duh).